# QString variable input skipped after double variable entered from keyboard with Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm trying to input QStrings and Doubles/Floats from the keyboard but after I entered a Double variable from the keyboard the program will skip the next QString input. What's the problem?

My program:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>

QTextStream cout(stdout);
QTextStream cin(stdin);


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString name, supplier;
    float price;
    char answer;

    cout << "Enter product name: ";
    cout.flush();
    name = cin.readLine();

    cout << "Enter product price: ";
    cout.flush();
    cin >> price;

    cout << "Enter product supplier: ";
    cout.flush();
    supplier = cin.readLine();

    cout << "Is the supplier the manufacturer? (Y/N): ";
    cout.flush();
    cin >> answer;

    cout << name << "-" << price << "-" << supplier << "-" << answer <<endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```

I can get the program to work if I enter the price as a QString then convert it to a double but that feels a bit redundant?

Why would it skip the supplier input after I entered the double variable?

Comment: Naming your stream `cout` and `cin` is a bad choice. It's way to easy to think you mean `std::cout` and `std::cin` when you use `cout` and `cin`. It makes the code hard to understand for everyone else reading it.

Comment: As for your problem, it's the same as a thousand duplicates here on stackoverflow.com (but using `std::cin` instead): Your reading of the floating point value doesn't read the newline in the input buffer.

Comment: Thank you. I will start using naming strategies. How do I correct the problem in my program so that it will work?

Answer (score 0):

After `cin >> price;` you need another `cin.readLine();` since reading a float doesn't read until the end of the line:

```
[...]
cout << "Enter product price: ";
cout.flush();
cin >> price;
cin.readLine();
[...]
```

Comment: That worked. I read on augustcouncil.com that it's better to input the variable as a string and then convert it. Do you agree?